# what technique to use to manually make a text have a blinking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, algorithm, timer

I know I can change the color of a text using this

```
$(#text).css('color', 'red');
```

How should my javscript be such that I can make it flash to red and black with an interval of about 200ms in between?

It'll be good if I can do something like this

```
    function loop() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            ChangeTextToRed();

            <pause for 300ms here>

            ChangeTextToBlack();
            loop();
        }, 300);
    }
```

But I know there's no thread.sleep in javascript

Comment: Use setInterval and a Boolean

Comment: what's not working in your `loop()` method?

Comment: If you like to do it in CSS(3) check the link http://www.john-smith.me/emulating--lt-blink-gt--using-webkit-css3-animation

Comment: I am curious. Why does this have the algorithm tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using setInterval and jquery's toggleClass() method, you can accomplish this very easily.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#text').toggleClass("blink");
}, 300);
```

You simply add/remove a class that has the other color. View a working sample on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UFfRc/

EDIT:
Just wanted to give a little more info. The benefit to this approach (using a class) is that you can customize it without editing the javascript. You can add transitions, movements, etc. Also, this will degrade gracefully on browsers that dont support css3 transitions. They will simply see the state change without a transition. Here's an example of that. http://jsfiddle.net/rRXGc/

With that said, be responsible. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) method:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // do something here
}, 300);
```

This allows you to execute some code at regular intervals (300ms in this example)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setInterval` and toggle between two classes.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var newClass = '.'+ $('#text').hasClass('black') ? 'red' : 'black';

    $('#text').attr('class', newClass);
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have used [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), you will have to do it twice:

```
function loop() {
    setTimeout(function () { // pause for 300ms before executing this:
        ChangeTextToRed();
        setTimeout(function () { // pause for 300ms before executing this:
            ChangeTextToBlack();
            loop();
        }, 300);
    }, 300);
}
```

or shorter:

```
function loop() {
    ChangeTextToRed();
    setTimeout(function () {
        ChangeTextToBlack();
        setTimeout(loop, 300);
    }, 300);
}
```

Of course, you could as well use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) and maintain a boolean flag on which change to make, but the above is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is not a large support CSS feature but you could use animation

```
#text{
   animation:blackred 400ms linear infinite; -webkit-animation:blackred 400ms linear infinite; -moz-animation:blackred 400ms linear infinite; -o-animation:blackred 400ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blackred{
0%{color:red;}
50%{color:black;}
100%{color:red;}
}


@-webkit-keyframes blackred{
0%{color:red;}
50%{color:black;}
100%{color:red;}
}

@-moz-keyframes blackred{
0%{color:red;}
50%{color:black;}
100%{color:red;}
}

@-o-keyframes blackred{
0%{color:red;}
50%{color:black;}
100%{color:red;}
}
```